# How to read Japanese school grades?

Tags: readings

I want to know how to read [Japanese school grades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_Japan), like 「小1」「中3」, etc.

Would be very thankful if both pronunciation and accent could be provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

小【しょう】, 中【ちゅう】 or 高【こう】, followed by いち/に/さん/よん/ご/ろく.

The pitch accent is always 平板 (flat/unaccented), i.e., しょうろく【LLHHH】, こうに【LHH】 and so on.

Somehow we do not usually say 大一 ～ 大四.

Comment: I think I may misunderstand. You say the pitch accent is flat and then show something which I thought meant that it was rising.

Comment: @user3856370 The first two morae of a Japanese word *must* have different pitch in Japanese. The term "flat" actually means "no falling point in or after the word". It's "Accent position: 0" in [this article](http://tell.cla.purdue.edu/hatasa/j-accent/unit-06.html). I understand this is confusing...

Comment: Then how do we usually express 大一 ～ 大四?

Comment: @古手梨花 大学1年生 and so on.